# Выбрать первые 3 новости из разных категорий

Tags: sql, mysql

Добрый день.
Есть таблица новостей и таблица категорий к новостям.
Вопрос: Как сделать выборку 3-х последних записей по всем новостям, одним запросом.

Comment: Здесь есть несколько способов, но не все будут работать под MySQL: [Как вывести по N строк из каждой группы?](http://sql-ex.ru/help/select16.php)

Comment: Вы бы хоть структуру Бд привели. а то не понятно все новости в одной таблице или каждая категория в своей? По какому принципу определяются последние? Может есть поле timestamp в котором хранится время создания новости?

Answer (score 2):

Работу запроса можно [посмотреть тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f818/1/0). Сам запрос таков:

```
SELECT t1.`art_id`, t1.`cid`, t1.`art_title`, COUNT(*) as `counter` 
  FROM `articles` t1 JOIN `articles` t2 ON t1.`cid` = t2.`cid` 
    AND t1.`art_id` <= t2.`art_id` 
GROUP BY t1.`cid`, t1.`art_id` 
  HAVING `counter` <= 3 
ORDER BY `cid`, `art_id` DESC;
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но попробовав этот метод на 1000000 записей - понял, что проще будет процедуру сделать.

Comment: @Проценко Александр, правильный подход.

Comment: И чем лучше процедурой?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Версия 1:
Тестовые данные [тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6df1/20), взяты из сообщения Deonis, правда, это перелопатит все данные.

```
SET @a:=0 AND @cid:=0;

SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        if(@cid=I.cid, @a:=@a+1, (@a:=1) AND (@cid:=I.cid)) counter, I.*
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            t.art_id,t.cid,t.art_title
        FROM
            `articles` t
        ORDER BY 
            t.cid ASC, t.art_id DESC
        LIMIT 
            100500 #без лимита Maria не вернет отсортированный массив
        ) I 
    ) I2 
WHERE 
    I2.counter < 4
```

Версия 2 для mysql 8.0+, Maria 10.2+:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY cid ASC, art_id DESC) AS counter
    FROM `articles` AS a
)

SELECT t.art_id,t.cid,t.art_title FROM t WHERE counter <= 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

Использовать JOIN и LIMIT

Comment: Это и так понятно, но мне нужно именно последние 3 новости со всех категорий, больше и меньше 3 новостей быть не должно.

Comment: > больше и меньше 3 новостей быть не должно.

Если в базе всего 2 новости, что тогда должно произойти? запросу выдумать еще одну новость?

Comment: Я не прав. Наверно, лучше использовать JOIN, а вложенный SELECT. Да и индексы настроить надо, если новостей очень много.